# Move data from one column to a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have database and in one column and someone had a code like this. This is just one entry of column

```
<span style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 40px; line-height: 2px;">&#8220;</span> Some text<span style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 40px;line-height:30px">&#8221;</span><br/>
<strong>Name, </strong><br/><br/> <strong style="font-style: italic;"> Location</strong><br/><br/><br/>
<span style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 40px; line-height: 2px;">&#8220;</span> Sometext<span style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 40px;line-height:30px">&#8221;</span><br/>
<strong>Name, </strong><br/><br/> <strong style="font-style: italic;"> Sydney</strong><br/><br/><br/>
```

In php all he is doing is

```
echo $row['table_name'];
```

Now I have created a separate table for this with fields

```
id, tName, tLocation, Text
```

I want to enter all the data in the above column to this table but as the data is too much so I cant do data entry

e.g the entry of above code will go like

```
tName = Name
tLocation = Sydney
Text = Some text
```

Can we archive this through some query or even PHP code? If yes then how

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can.

Comment: A bit wrong readable code. It would deserve reformatting for better reading. Column of DB table? HTML table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done easily with SQL, however you can make a script and match the content using regex.

```
$data = <<<EOD
<span style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 40px; line-height: 2px;">&#8220;</span> Some text<span style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 40px;line-height:30px">&#8221;</span><br/>
<strong>Name, </strong><br/><br/> <strong style="font-style: italic;"> Location</strong><br/><br/><br/>
<span style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 40px; line-height: 2px;">&#8220;</span> Sometext<span style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 40px;line-height:30px">&#8221;</span><br/>
<strong>Name, </strong><br/><br/> <strong style="font-style: italic;"> Sydney</strong><br/><br/><br/>

EOD;

echo $data;
echo "<pre>";

//Name part
preg_match_all('@<strong>(.+), </strong><br/><br/> <strong style="font-style: italic;">@', $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);

//sometext part
preg_match_all('@<span style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 40px; line-height: 2px;">&#8220;</span>(.+)<span style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 40px;line-height:30px">&#8221;</span><br/>@', $data,$matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);

//Location part
preg_match_all('@<strong style="font-style: italic;">(.+)</strong>@', $data,$matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Comment: awesome man, although I took care of that but this works like charm, will use this one :)